# Elasticsearch need AND query instead OR

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to search posts with some prefixes (212, 215) and in certain node (663).

This query is searching posts with OR prefix operator. But i need a query to search with `AND` operator. How to do it? This query is generated by CMS:

```json
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "node":663
               }
            },
            {
               "terms":{
                  "prefix":[
                     "215",
                     "212"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "type":{
                           "value":"post"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "type":{
                           "value":"thread"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "must":{
            "match_all":{
               
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "date":"desc"
      }
   ],
   "size":8000,
   "docvalue_fields":[
      "discussion_id",
      "user",
      "date"
   ],
   "_source":false
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data to explain the problem better?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for docs that have a list of values for `prefix` containing both 212 and 215, you should use separate queries:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter":[
            ...
            {"match":{"prefix":"212"}},
            {"match":{"prefix":"215"}},
            ...
         ],
         ...
}
```